# Woo-commerce get all the comments for by product id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

What I need to achieve is to get all comments from all products in Woocommerce. I have try te

```
get_comments( array( 'post_type' => 'product') );
```

But it give me all the comments not for the particular product id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello after doing some research I got the what I want here is the code which return all approved post for the particular product.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'post_ID' =>$product->id,  // Product Id
    'status' => "approve", // Status you can also use 'hold', 'spam', 'trash', 
    'number' => 1  // Number of comment you want to fetch I want latest approved post soi have use 1
    );
$comments = get_comments($args);
```

Comment: how are you getting product id without loop

Comment: I have loaded product by using `$product = new WC_Product($productId);` i need to create home page where it will show static one product.

Comment: I have added option in admin panel where admin can add the product id which he need to show on the home page. and i have used that database product id.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code to get the latest product review.

```
$args = array (
'post_type' => 'product', 
'post_id' => $product->get_id(),  // Product Id
'status' => "approve", // Status you can also use 'hold', 'spam', 'trash', 
'number' => 1  // Number of comment you want to fetch I want latest approved comment. But if you want all comments for specific product then you should remove 'number'.
);
 $comments = get_comments($args);
```